# Does DBMS actually bypass OS and run over filesystem to manage disk space?

Tags: database, disk

I am working on the [slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RaqaZ5p2TcX-Nn21rFlxDyzgCNdGCi1H/view) offered by [UCB cs186 fall 2020 course](http://cs186berkeley.net/fa20/), it says:

In terms of disk space management, there are 2 proposals:

- Talk to the storage device directly, or
- Run our own over filesystem (FS). Bypass the OS, allocate a single large “contiguous” file on
  an empty disk

I don't get the 2nd proposal. I do understand that leveraging filesystem is great because it does a lot for us, but:

- Why bypassing OS? Why not use filesystem APIs offered through OS to manage disk space?
- What does "use FS but bypass OS" really mean - I thought most systems use FS through OS. Is that not the case in the world of DBMS?

Comment: If you only use and believe the OS, it will be a problem because it doesn't know anything about the DB. It makes something without considering it. For example, it schedules the processes for the OS, not specifically for the DB. So, DBs use buffer pools, manage the disk space and makes some arrangements for itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBMS aims to solve the problem: disk space is large but slow, memory is small but fast, how to make our DB large and fast? As a result, it needs to solve both memory management and disk management.

Typically, DBMS relies on OS filesystem for disk management but will bypass OS (i.e. mmap) for memory (aka buffer pool) management.

- Disk management: Very few DBMS ([BlueStore](https://ceph.io/community/new-luminous-bluestore/), [ScyllaDB](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/08/25/scylla-student-projects-part-ii-implementing-an-async-userspace-file-system/)) do bypass OS filesystem and talk to the raw device directly, but due to the issues such as complexity, portability, and insignificant speedup (~10% according to Andy Pavlo), they’re not common.
- Memory management: Most DBMS has a logical understanding of workload/transactions, while OS is unaware of the relationship between different buffers in memory. This makes it beneficial for DB to manage memory on its own.

Credits to Aashray#4143 and miller#0114 in CMU 15-445 unofficial community (Discord).